# Does Dapper have a limit to the size of the Query's SELECT statement?

Tags: dapper

I'm using Dapper to do a dynamic Query on a SQL string that is quite large.  If I paste it into Word, I get the following stats:

> - Words: 15,433
> - Characters (with spaces): 103,366
> - Lines:  1,637

The problem is that when it executes nothing fails but I get an empty IEnumerable result.

So the question is does Dapper have a limit on this size?  Or is it failing quietly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there is no problem with Dapper, just me!  I have two versions of the database and one has data, the other doesn't.  I was running against the dataless version.

Comment: Hahaha, awesome. Happens to the best of us. :D